# How to list all posts from custom post type (taxonomy)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display all posts from taxonomy. I have posts type(Docs) and taxonomy (type_docs) I'm trying to list all posts from that post type. My code is like this but it is not working

```
<?php
  $custom_terms = get_terms('type_docs');

 foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
   wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'docs',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type_docs',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
        ),
    ),
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a> 
 <br>';
    endwhile;
   }
}
?>
```

I’m trying to only list all posts from taxonomy, can somebody help with this?

Comment: provide environmental details such as `wordpress` version etc.

Comment: @KiranManiya Wordpress 5.2..2 running on localhost

Comment: Do you mean posts that have a specific taxonomy `term`? If that's the case, your loop needs to be in the `foreach`, as the `$args` variable will continue to be reset until the end of the `foreach`, and once the `foreach` is finished, that's the last one will be the value of the `$args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get exactly why you want to do thing like that but here is the solution:

```
<?php

// Get your custom terms
$custom_terms = get_terms('type_docs');

// Prepare the query
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'docs',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array()
);

// Prepare the array to receive terms tax_query
$terms_query = array();

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {

  // Add terms to the tax query
  $args['tax_query'][] = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'type_docs',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
  );
}

// Get the posts (or you could do your new WP_Query)
$posts = get_posts($args);

// Display
foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```